# How many lines of form $px+2y=1$ are normal to parabola $y^2=4ax$

Tags: conic-sections

The line can be written as $$y=-\frac P2 x+1$$

The normal to a parabola is $$y=mx-2am-am^3$$

Comparing them we get 
$$m=-\frac P2$$

And 
$$2am+am^3=-1$$
$$-aP-a\frac{P^3}{8}=-1$$
$$aP+\frac{aP^3}{8}=1$$

Now there is now way to tell. One would think that since it’s a cubic polynomial, we would have 3 values, but the answer is one, so that theory is dismissed. Am I missing something here?

Comment: What is you definition of a normal line to the parabola? That the line is orthogonal to the tangent line at some point, and is going through that same point? Is $a$ given, so the parabola fixed, or is $p$ given and the line fixed, or is it about all combinations?

Comment: @HennoBrandsma $a$ is not given

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image]

Note that the given line $px+2y=1$ passes through the fixed point $(0,\frac12)$, which lies outside the parabola $y^2=4ax$. Geometrically, as seen in the graph, there can be only one normal line to the parabola that passes the point $(0,\frac12)$. (There would be three normals if the fixed point that the line passes lie inside the parabola.)

Analytically, the cubic equation $ap+\frac{ap^3}{8}=1$, which is
$$p^3+8p-\frac8a=0$$

has only one real root because its discriminate $\Delta =-8^2 (4+\frac {27}{a^2})\le 0$, yielding one valid normal as well.

Comment: Wait there is a discriminant for cubic equations too? I wasn’t aware

Comment: @Aditya - correct. check the link https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cubic_equation

Comment: @Aditya he just meant that the it's derivative has no critical points and therefore has only one root.

Answer (score 0):

Parameterize the parabola as $\gamma(t) = (at^2,2at)$, now notice that the equation of normal at a parameter point $t$:

$$ y+tx= 2at+ at^3$$

And compare this with the original equation $y+ \frac{P}{2} x = \frac12$, we find $t= \frac{P}{2}$ and $ \frac12 = 2at + at^3$, substituting $t$ in terms of $P$ in the cubic:

$$ 0 = aP + \frac{a}{8} P^3 - \frac12$$
Wlog let $a>0$, then we find by Descartes rule of signs that the equation has one root in the interval $(0,\infty)$ and no roots in the interval $(-\infty,0)$